# How can I apply background image on click without it getting overriden by background color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a sort of customization menu, where the user can select background images and colors for a few elements on the page. My issue is specifically with the `body` tag. The user can apply both a background color + a transparent background image to the `body`, but the problem is.. if the user selects an image then the color, the background image gets removed.

I know where my issue is but I am not able to find a way to fix it.

so when you apply first the color, then the image this is what gets displayed:

```
<body style="background: url("./image/STARS.png";) rgb(255, 165, 2);">
```

but if you go back and select a color the style changes and the image gets overriden by the color selected like this:

```
<body style="background: rgb(255, 165, 2);">
```

How can I make it so that when the image is selected, for it to be applied in the `"background-image=""` tag in the style instead of in the `background=""`

Here is my JS for both: (the bottom one is the one that applies the image)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.theme-colors-menu .color').forEach(color => {
        color.onclick = () => {
            let background = color.style.background;
            document.querySelector('body').style.background = background;
        }
    });
    document.querySelectorAll('.theme-colors-img-bgr .color').forEach(bgrImg => {
        bgrImg.onclick = () => {
            let background = bgrImg.style.backgroundImage;
            document.querySelector('body').style.backgroundImage = background;
        }
    });
```

I have also tried this for the 2nd function but it was still applied in the `background` tag instead of the `background-image` one:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.theme-colors-img-bgr .color').forEach(bgrImg => {
        bgrImg.onclick = () => {
            let background = bgrImg.style.backgroundImage;
            $("body").css("background-image", background);
        }
    });
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue here causing it to be in the background tag rather than the background-image?

Comment: instead of background use background-image and background-color.. they're different properties independent of each other (camel case in js)

Comment: thanks your comment made me realize I could have simply changed my top function to `$("body").css("background-color", background);` but for some reason I was fully just focused on the bottom one and didnt think of changing the top function.

Comment: yeah, those kind of things can drive you nuts.. glad I could help

Comment: @zergski true hhhh.. thanks again for pointing it out, I guess my brain was just not braining enough. XD

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work, at the end I changed the top function to this and it solved my issue:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.theme-colors-menu .color').forEach(color => {
        color.onclick = () => {
            let background = color.style.background;
            $("body").css("background-color", background);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Color could be applied as **background-color** property.

```
<body style="background: url('./image/STARS.png'); background-color: rgb(255, 165, 2);">
```

[Example of solution](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: I know how it works, my issue was that when I selcted the color it was overriding the image, I have posted an answer to my question now I got it solved